# Tidy data with both multiple variables in column names and multiple observations per row

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have an untidy dataset.

```
dat_untidy <- data.frame(AFDWSDF = c(10, 20),
                         AFDWSDFQUAL = c("a","b"),
                         TPFCE = c(1, 1.5),
                         TPFCEQUAL = c("c","d"))
```

Variable names contain 3 or 4 pieces of information that I would like to decompose and store as individual variables:

```
dat_tidy <- data.frame(Var_X = c(rep("AFDW", 2),rep("TP", 2)),
                   Var_Y = c(rep("SD", 2), rep("FC", 2)),
                   Var_Z = c(rep("F", 2), rep("E", 2)),
                   Value = c(10, 20, 1, 1.5),
                   Qualifier = c("a","b","c","d"))
```

The variable names are of the form xxxxyyz. The 'xxxx', 'yy', and 'z' should each become a variable value. 'yy' and 'z' are always 2 and 1 characters, respectively, but 'xxxx' can be any number of characters.

On top of this, as in my example, the variables are (mostly) in pairs, with 'xxxxyyz' adjacent to 'xxxxyyzQUAL$' (qualifier code for the datum value). The "...QUAL$"s also need to be gathered into a tidy variable.

From the Anscombe example in the [vingette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html#multiple-observations-per-row), it feels like `pivot_longer()` could be an elegant solution, but I need help defining the regex pattern. I suspect it might be simpler to break this into two steps, perhaps first a `pivot_longer()` to collect the variable names into a so-called `Var_XYZ`, with associated `Value` and `Qualifier`, and then a `mutate()` to decompose the `Var_XYZ`, but I can't put my finger on this either.

I'm a complete novice with regex, and most comfortable with dplyr for the manipulations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: were you able to create the first dataframe with $ sign in column name. I don't think R will allow

Comment: You're correct, not possible to build that first dataframe with $ in the column name, my mistake. Those characters are included in the raw data I'm reading in from spreadsheet though. Can be dealt with separately from this issue, thanks for editing the post.

Comment: As it turns out, inconsistent pairing of value and qualifier columns in my real data (which I did not emphasize in my question) breaks the otherwise nice solutions by @Edward and Wimpel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a combination of `reshape` from the **stats** package and `separate` from the **tidyr** package.

First, store the pairs of variables into the "Qualifiers" and "Vars".

```
Quals <- grep("QUAL$", names(dat_untidy), value=TRUE)
Vars <- sub("QUAL", "", Quals)
```

Then, reshape into long form and separate `Vars` into the three `_X`, `_Y`, `_Z` columns.

```
library(tidyr)

dat_tidy <- reshape(dat_untidy, direction="long", varying=list(Vars, Quals),
        v.names=c("Value","Qualifier"),
        timevar="Vars", times=Vars) %>%
  separate(col="Vars", into=c("Var_X","Var_Y","Var_Z"), 
           remove = TRUE, sep = -c(3,1)) %>%  # Reverse separator
  select(-id)

rownames(dat_tidy) <- NULL

dat_tidy
```

---

```
  Var_X Var_Y Var_Z Value Qualifier
1  AFDW    SD     F  10.0         a
2  AFDW    SD     F  20.0         b
3    TP    FC     E   1.0         c
4    TP    FC     E   1.5         d
```

Comment: Elegant, thanks. I got it to work by applying it separately to the selections of columns that had and that did not have associated qualifier columns (modifying parameters of the `reshape()' call for the latter), and then `bind_rows()` the resulting two data frames.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a data.table solution the should work...

```
library( data.table )
library( stringr )

#set untidy data to data.table format
setDT(dat_untidy)

#get names of columns not ending on QUAL
  cols <- names( dat_untidy )[!grepl( "QUAL$", names( dat_untidy ) ) ]
  #[1] "AFDWSDF" "TPFCE" 
  Var_X <- stringr::str_sub( cols,  1, -4 )
  #[1] "AFDW" "TP"
  Var_Y <- stringr::str_sub( cols, -3, -2 )
  #[1] "SD" "FC"
  Var_Z <- stringr::str_sub( cols, -1, -1 )  
  #[1] "F" "E"

#build regex patterns
  Var_X_pattern <- paste0( "(", paste0("^", Var_X, collapse = "|" ), ").*" )
  #[1] "(^AFDW|^TP).*"
  Var_Y_pattern <- paste0( ".*(", paste0(Var_Y, collapse = "|" ), 
                           ")(", paste0(Var_Z, "$", collapse = "|" ), ")" ) 
  #[1] ".*(SD|FC)(F$|E$)"
  Var_Z_pattern <- paste0( ".*(", paste0(Var_Z, "$", collapse = "|" ), ")" ) 
  #[1] ".*(F$|E$)"

#melt to long format (read, and then ignore, warning)
DT <- melt( dat_untidy, measure.vars = names(dat_untidy), variable.factor = FALSE )

#create columns
DT[, `:=`( Var_X = gsub( Var_X_pattern, "\\1", variable ),
           Var_Y = gsub( Var_Y_pattern, "\\1", variable ),
           Var_Z = gsub( Var_Z_pattern, "\\1", variable ) ) ][]

#create group_row_id
DT[, row_id := rowid( variable ) ][]
#create final output by joining, and then dropping the row_id column
DT[ !grepl("QUAL", variable ), .(Var_X, Var_Y, Var_Z, Value = value, row_id ) ][DT, Qualifier := i.value, on = .(Var_X, row_id) ][, row_id := NULL][]
```

**output**

```
#    Var_X Var_Y Var_Z Value Qualifier
# 1:  AFDW    SD     F    10         a
# 2:  AFDW    SD     F    20         b
# 3:    TP    FC     E     1         c
# 4:    TP    FC     E   1.5         d
```

Comment: This would've worked great, but I'm too unfamiliar with data.table to modify this to work on my real data, which were more complicated than my example in what turned out to be an important way.